# This HTML doesn't work on IPhone, any idea why?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I have this simple html written with help of TailwindCSS. When you click the button, it opens "menu" using `focus-within` and `active` selectors:

[Demo on play.tailwindcss.com](https://play.tailwindcss.com/dBsDmPTcoV)

```html
<div class="group relative inline-block p-3 ml-7">
  <button type="button" class="border-neutral-600 border px-1 rounded-md">...</button>

  <div class="absolute left-0 top-10 flex  flex-col rounded-md border border-neutral-500 bg-neutral-100 px-2 py-1 
              invisible group-focus-within:visible group-active:visible">
    <div class="cursor-pointer hover:underline">Do amazing stuff</div>
    <div class="cursor-pointer hover:underline"> Go back</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Expected result:

[image]

On an IPhone it doesn't open the menu, no matter the browser (safari, chrome).

Any idea?

Comment: Mobile devices don’t have hover events.

Comment: It's not hover. And it works perfectly fine on Android or any other touch screen.

Comment: @Alamakanambra If you add `ontouchstart=""` attrbute to a button, does it solves issue?

Comment: @IharAliakseyenka it shows itself and then disappears...